# Unable to see RestoreOption in jenkins plugin JobConfigHistory

Tags: jenkins

I have deleted a few jobs from Jenkins by mistake. so, I installed plugin **JobConfigHistory** to restore my jobs. but I am not seeing the restore option for my deleted job in the DeletedJob section of this plugin.

[image]

How to enable this option?

Answer (score 0):

You must have installed the **JobConfigHistory** plugin **BEFORE** any deletions in order to be able to restore. It's the plugin that maintains the history in the `${JENKINS_HOME}/config-hstory` directory. It is not a time machine.

Try restore from OS Backup. If you were not running backups, then I guess that's not an option for you either.

Comment: I have installed before deleting files !!! And I am getting Restore button for admin deleted Job but not for SYSTEM deleted jobs

Comment: Well, you did say, _"I deleted jobs from Jenkins so, I installed plugin"_, suggesting otherwise. Can you see  folder on disk, `${JENKINS_HOME}/config-history/jobs<JOBNAME>_deleted_<timestamp>`? Is your job in a [nested folder](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33998) ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Our Jenkins is deployed on the AWS server and I do not have access of same. So i can not check ${JENKINS_HOME}. Yes, I have a nested folder structure. i tried to debug this issue, I found out that the admin role has this option to restore it's job but whereas SYSTEM role does not have.

Comment: I identified a different bug...[JENKINS-63606](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-63606). If you have access to Groovy System console, write a little script to move jobs/<folder>/jobs/JOB_deleted_01234... From folder level to root level, then restore. If yours us a separate permission issue, create a new bug and link (is related to) the two.

Comment: Yes, U are correct !!! even i am seeing the same bug

Comment: I'll update my answer later to include this details, then you can mark as accepted/+ve.